# How to negate a comparer in C++ 17?

Tags: c++

What is the right way by a given comparer like this

```
auto comp = [](int a, int b) { return a < b;}
```

construct its negation that returns `!comp(a, b)`?

Comment: it is interesting that `!comp(a, b)` sorts `std::set` incorrectly

Comment: That's because the comparator for a `set` must return `false` if the two arguments are equivalent, which isn't the case for `!(a < b)`. Use `comp(b, a)` instead of `!comp(a, b)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the following functor that negates the result of the wrapped function
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/not_fn